# Search and replace characters in string from the list

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have two dict's like this,

```
in_dict = {
    '1': 'active_rate',
    '2': 'purchase_per_active'
}

formula = {
    'total_purchase': 'B1*B2'
}
```

I need to find the integers in the value of `formula` dict `'B1*B2'` and then get the value for integer corresponding to the integers from the `in_dict` dictionary and finally replace `B1` with `active_rate` and `B2` with `purchase_per_active`.

- STEP 1: Extract numbers from `formula` dict. e.g `['1','2']` in our case.
- STEP 2: Search for the keys in `in_dict` dict and get the corresponding values.
- STEP 3: Replace in the `formula` dict for values generated in STEP 2.

So, final `formula` dict should be like

```
formula = {
    'total_purchase': 'active_rate*purchase_per_active'
}
```

The code so far

```
for key, value in formula.items():
    numbers = re.findall("\d+", value)               # ['1','2']
    values = [in_dict.get(num) for num in numbers]   # ['active_rate', 'purchase_per_active']
```

Now, how to replace the `'B1'` with `'active_rate'` and `'B2'` with `'purchase_per_active'`?

The example shown here is just for sample. The code nature should be generic.

Comment: Are there always just 2 variables? Are the variables in the formula always a number prefixed with 'B'?

Comment: No it can have N variables and numbers are always prefixed with Character. Something like Excel sheets. It can be like C1*C3 given 1 and 3 are dict keys provided to us,

Comment: Are they always prefixed by _a_ character, or by one or more uppercase characters, like Excel (cell AB2, for example).

Comment: @Stephan Its just single character. You can think of the formula as excel formula like B2*B3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression substitution using a function to directly lookup each of the parameters:

```
import re

in_dict = {
    '1': 'active_rate',
    '2': 'purchase_per_active'
}

formula = {
    'total_purchase': 'B1*B2'
}

def lookup(number):
    return in_dict[number.group(1)]

for key, value in formula.items():
    formula[key] = re.sub("[a-zA-Z](\d+)", lookup, value)

print formula
```

This gives the following output:

> {'total_purchase': 'active_rate*purchase_per_active'}

To me it might make more sense if `in_dict` stored keys such as 'B1', 'C1'.

```
import re

in_dict = {
    'A1': 'active_rate1',
    'A2': 'purchase_per_active1',
    'B1': 'active_rate2',
    'B2': 'purchase_per_active2'
}

formula = {
    'total_purchase': 'B1*B2',
    'total_purchase2': 'A1*A2'
}

def lookup(cell):
    return in_dict[cell.group(1)]

for key, value in formula.items():
    formula[key] = re.sub("([a-zA-Z]\d+)", lookup, value)

print formula
```

> {'total_purchase2': 'active_rate1*purchase_per_active1',
>   'total_purchase': 'active_rate2*purchase_per_active2'}

Comment: Can you update your answer if the in_dict keys are 'A1','A2'?

Comment: Simply move `[a-zA-Z]` inside the parentheses of the regular expression and change the keys in `in_dict`. e.g. `re.sub("([a-zA-Z]\d+)",`    In this case care should be taken to ensure all suitable values are in `in_dict` or there will be a key exception. The lookup function would need to return a suitable value in this case.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The in_dict keys will be 'A1','A2' instead of just numbers and formula dict will remain same i.e `formula = {
    'total_purchase': 'B1*B2'
}`. Currently changing the regex and in_dict keys raises keyerror.

Comment: I have added a 2nd version to my answer. In this one, `cell.group(1)` will hold 'B1', it is up to you how to handle this. For example, you could discard the letter and just lookup the number using the original `in_dict`, and then prefix the letter to the returned value, e.g. "A_active_rate".